# How to replace View with set constraintVertical_bias using some ConstraintLayout component?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout

I use ConstraintLayout in my project and I would like to achieve result which is the result of below code. The thing is I want to set *tab_layout* in the vertical center between *helper.view* and end of the *viewpager*. I was trying with guideline but I need vertical percentage alignment in relation to *viewpager*. Is there an option to do this without using any helper views? It is important that the *tab_layout's* top constraint has to be in 0.85 vertical bottom between *viewpager's* top and bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_green"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header.logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@android:mipmap/sym_def_app_icon"
        android:contentDescription="@string/login.screen.header.logo" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header.logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/login.screen.helper.help.button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/helper.view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/viewpager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/viewpager"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.85"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:background="@color/editTextBorder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/helper.view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/viewpager"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottom.guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="32dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/login.screen.helper.help.button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom.guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        style="@style/mediumStyle"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="text1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/login.screen.helper.policy.button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom.guideline"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        style="@style/mediumStyle"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="text2"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what I would like to achieve, but without using helper.view.

[image]

Comment: what happens when you remove `id=helper.view"`?

Comment: tab_layout goes into bottom

Comment: can you elaborate on this please "tab_layout's top constraint has to be in 0.85 vertical bottom between viewpager's top and bottom"? do you mean you need margin between viewpager and tabs? because I am able to achieve what you said without helper

Comment: I mean I need something what works like vertical guideline constraintGuide_percent but between viewpager's top and viewpager's bottom. Its value has to be 0.85 and therefore constraintVertical_bias for helper is set 0.85. When I use helper it works because i can set top constraint for tab_layout, so finally I can set tab_layout in the vertical center between line 0.85 and viewpager's bottom. The point is I would like to find "cleaner" solution.